# Videos loading but not playing with mediaelement.js in Chrome 27.x when including subtitle tracks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, mediaelement.js, subtitle

I'm using mediaelement.js to load videos with subtitle tracks.

All was working well until I updated my Chrome browser to 27.x. Now if a subtitle track is included, the video will load but not play. The video buffers fine (I can manually scrub through it), but neither the play button or javascript play() will play the video. The loading gif just sits there, and I don't see any errors in the console.

It works in all other browsers I've tested, including Chrome 26.x.

If I remove the subtitle source element, the videos load and play correctly in Chrome.

(This is my first SO question so any tips would be appreciated, thanks)

Comment: Can you create a minimal test case of this issue and put it online?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on day four of trying to solve this same issue and came across this question. It's happening on Mac and Windows. Troubleshooting is aggravated by what appears to be local caching -- if I comment out the `<track>` the video plays; When I re-enable it and reload, it also plays, but then if I close out of the browser it will no longer work until I comment the `<track>` out again.

If I disable mediaelement and test with native HTML5 video, the problem does not manifest itself.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better as a comment since it isn't really answer.

Comment: Yes. I would have loved to have added it as a comment, except there's no "Add Comment" button showing for me on the question. I reloaded the page a couple times before giving up and posting it as an answer, preparing myself for the inevitable comment pointing out that it should have been posted as a comment instead. But to reiterate, yes, I absolutely agree with you.

Comment: I also considered opening my own question, but it seemed like adding to this one might ultimately be more useful.

Comment: hmm.... I forgot about that privilege limitation. Since the author of this question doesn't seem to be responding to comments perhaps it would be best for you to open a new question. Then you could engage with other users in the comments and would have a much higher chance of getting an answer. As a side note thanks for getting involved. It's everybody working together that makes StackOverflow great.

Comment: Yes, you have to have 50 rep points before you are allowed to comment on other user's posts.

Comment: I guess I see the point in that. But I'd love to get grivvr back to his original question to see if we can help each other. Anyhoo, enough chatter (and auto prompts not to chatter). I'll consider posting as my own question, but have to log off for a bit.

Comment: Ah sorry Brook, I assumed I'd get email notifications if anyone responded. I'm a total noob at this. I'll revisit the code and as suggested above, post a minimal test example.